# Dynamically adding descriptors to a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a class with lots of attributes and to cut down on the complexity I'm trying to re-write it by dynamically creating them. I've tried the following:

```
class D_test: 
    def __get__(self, obj = None, obj_type= None): 
        print (f'{self} yeah!!') 
    def __set__(self, obj, value): 
        print (f'{self} {obj} {value}') 

class Blagh:
    pass

setattr(Blagh, 'test', D_test)

x = Blagh()

x.test

In [18]: x.test                                                                 
Out[18]: __main__.D_test
```

My understanding is that the above should call the `__get__` of the descriptor. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It's not clear why this would be an improvement over `class Blagh: test = D_test()`.

Comment: I've a bunch of custom classes that I'm assigning to a largish list of attributes. Rather than have hundreds of entries in the class I wanted to do it programmatically. Easier for me to change stuff, less error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the descriptor, otherwise you just attach the descriptor class to `Blagh`:

```
setattr(Blagh, 'test', D_test())
```